# Inspect python with block

Tags: python

Is it possible to get the source code of the with block?

E.g.:

```
with print_source():
  someFunction()
  someOtherFunction()

# "someFunction()\nsomeOtherFunction()\n" should be printed
```

If not, is it something that is available in Python C API?

I've tried using `sys.settrace`, but it only catches function calls, which with-block isn't.

Comment: What do you mean, get the source code?  You wrote the code and posted it.  What other source do you want?  Does `inspect` help at all?

Comment: I suspect the answer is "no", as the `with` block is not an object in its own right (as opposed to a module or a function, for example). It is more akin to an `if` block, which just affects program flow. But I'm not an expert on the internals, hence this is not a full answer

Comment: @Prune I meant to get the source code in runtime. Inspect needs a function to be passed to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not super straightforward to do this because a `with` block isn't an object in its own right like a module or function. However, while I don't have a full implementation, I have some suggestions from which you should be able to put something together:

- In the `__enter__()` function of the `print_source` context manager, use `inspect.stack()` to get the current frames on the stack. The top frame is the `__enter__` method, and the next one down is the function where the `with` block lives. I will call this the "function frame".
- The function frame info includes the line number of the `with print_source` line. You will need this shortly.
- Pass the frame from the function frame info to `inspect.getsourcelines()` to get all the source lines from the function (like it says on the tin). This function also identifies the line number of the `def foo():` line.
- Using the line number of the `with ...` line, offset by the line number of the `def ...` line, you can identify the indentation level of the `with` block. Iterate through the source lines of the function, starting with the one after the `with` block, until you hit another line with the same (or smaller) indentation as the `with ...` line. You have now identified all the source within the `with` block.

Things that I have not allowed for (but should be possible) include:

- comment lines within the `with` block that have smaller indentation than the rest of the block (should be easy to just check if a line is a comment and ignore it for the end-of-block check). You probably also want to handle the case where a `with` block is the last code in a file, but is followed by comments that have smaller indentation. Do something like tracking the line number of the last code that had the correct indentation.
- multiple context managers being combined, like `with cm1(), cm2(), cm3():`. I haven't checked how this appears in the stack
- having the `with` statement spread across multiple lines. I haven't checked which line the frame reports the statement as being on, but I have a strong suspicion that it is the line with the `:`

Hope that gives enough to get something working!

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot! `inspect.stack()[1]`  of `__enter__` has the first line and in `__exit__` it gives the last line of the with block. I just need to add the lines in between, parse it into AST and get the body.

Comment: Hm, no, alas multiline with isn't so easy to handle.

Comment: Might require some more complex parsing of the source lines to handle it, but seems like it should be achievable. Maybe walk backwards through the source lines to find the nearest line starting with `with`?